# First image from Wordpress Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to extract the first image from a post, I found this code but this shows the last image from posts instead (example: http://zonadictoz.com.ar), I don't Know why!

```
function myPostImage()
{
  global $post, $posts;
  $first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
  $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
  $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
    $first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
  }
  return $first_img;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you just select first image that is attached to the post from database?

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML is generally considered bad. Use `DomDocument` instead.

Comment: If you insist on using regex, `var_dump` your matches and see if your first image is in the array at all. You could just be calling the wrong index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [features image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) field is a much more robust solution, but with regards to your code you could change *preg_match_all()* with **preg_match()** to make sure only the first match is captured:

```
<?php
$match = preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);

if ( $match )
    $first_img = $matches[1];
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you apply your code to my function?, thanks

Comment: I achieved adapt your code but it seems that is still picking up from the last image, and not the first, how I can reverse it?

Comment: It's quite likely that the last image is the only image tag that is **matched** by your regular expression. That is exactly why you should not use regular expressions to parse HTML, it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved adapt the code abobe but it seems that is still picking up from the last image, and not the first, how I can reverse it?